# Excel file issues in OneDrive

Tags: excel, onedrive

I was working on an `excel file` from past 1 week. This file was saved only on One drive and not on my disk. Till yesterday everything was fine.

But today when I open the file, everything I worked from Tuesday was gone! The file contained only the work from Monday!

Is this a bug? or something else? It would be really helpful if someone could help me solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird behavior! **by default**, the Excel Online saves your work automatically.

> I suggest opening a new support request at [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection) and [Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/home/contact)